# How to get a list of all permissions which have been explicitly granted to an address in multichain

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info-api

I wanted to check the permissions that have been granted to an address. what API command or cli command should i use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **listpermissions** to Return a list of all permissions which have been explicitly granted to address.

Answer (score 0):

listpermissions will provide the list of all permissions across all nodes in the network, unless you pass through the specific permissions that you are checking for, and specific address you are looking for as a parameter in the format

listpermissions (permissions=*) (addresses=*) (verbose=false)
See https://www.multichain.com/developers/json-rpc-api/ for further explanation